# Filling a datagridview column separately from the datasettableadapter

Tags: datagridview

I have set up a data grid view and linked it to my data and filled it with the adapter and all that is working just fine. What I would like to do is add a column to the beginning of the data grid view and add an image to the first column that has the file name of the current first column of which will wind up as the second column.

I have added the column and set it up for images already and also set a default image if the value is not set. I am having trouble figuring out how to read what is in column2 and then loading the image with the file name (edited a bit to match my naming schemes) into column1. I cant figure out if I need to do this to the grid view, the datasettableadapter, or some other place. I tried iterating throw the rows to read cell2 then load image for cell1 but I can't set currentrow.

I ended up using CellPainting because CellFormating was giving me some strange output. Below is the code I use. Cells[0] is the cell I would like to put the image in. Cells[1] is the name of the image that I use as file name.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        string monsterName = "";

        try
        {
            if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "monsterNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn")
            {
                if (e.Value != null && e.RowIndex > -1)
                {
                    monsterName = (string)this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value;
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Chad\Pictures\Dark Summoner\C_" + monsterName + @".png");
                }
            }
        }

        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
           toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = monsterName + " image file does not exist.";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this in a few ways.

1) Handle the datagridview's CellFormatting event and populate the cell's image in there. The event has a parameter that has access to the current row/column it is trying to format. So you could read the image file from cell 2 and set the image of cell 1 in here based on that.

2) Pre-populate the image data in your datasource. So if your dataadapter is filling a DataTable for example, you could load/populate the image in the datatable after loading your datatable.